# Center textview on RelativeLayout, when other textview it's null (or dont have text)

Tags: java, android, textview

I followed [this](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/?replytocom=3075#respond) tutorial, for now it's working nice, but i only have a problem, i need to center vertically the "Title" textview, when "Detail" textview text it's null or empty, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVHRO.jpg). I tried this (http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/), and it works, but the problem it's that if i use setVisibility(View.GONE), all the details from all the items, dissapear, and just title get centered., any help appreciated, thanks

EDIT: Fixed this way

```
String detailView = String.valueOf(rowData.mDetail);
             detail.setText(detailView);
             detail.setVisibility(detailView.equals("null") ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to setVisible(View.VISIBLE) when you are recycling a view.

```
String detail = "some detail....";
detailTextView.setVisible(detail == null ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
```

Hope this helps